# How to write a dynamic SQL query for a select where clause?

Tags: execute, execute-immediate

If variable1 is null
      Select *from table
     Where condition1 
     And condition 2
 And a is not null and b is not null
Else
     Select * from table 
     Where condition 1
     And conditon 2
And a is null and b is null

How to write this as a dynamic SQL query since only the last 2 conditions change in 'if and else'?

Comment: Gotta know what database manager you are dealing with???

Answer (score 0):

This may or may not work, depending on which DB is being used.. Give it a try.

```
Select * from ConditionalWhere
Where condition1 = 1
  And condition2 = 1
  AND  CASE When (variable1 is null) 
              And ([a] is not null) 
              and ([b] is not null) 
              Then 1
            When (variable1 is not null)                        
              and ([a] is null)     
              and ([b] is null)     
              Then 1 
            Else 0
       End = 1
```

Comment: If variable1 is not null
      Select X from table into y
     Where a=b
     And c=d
 And e is not NULL and f is not NULL
Else
     Select x from table into y
     Where a=b
     And c=d
And e is NULL and f is NULL

Slightly modified my question. In the above case how to write a single dynamic query?

Comment: @MahaLakshmi Please use the above pattern to construct your own next SQL